# Could the hypothesis of regular matter converting into dark matter help to find out what the dark matter is?

Tags: dark-matter, matter

Could the hypothesis of regular matter converting into dark matter ([Dark Matter from Exponential Growth](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.127.191802), free version available [from the arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.16572) with a rather different title) help to find out what the dark matter is?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it policy not to review new papers, which is essentially what the question asks.

Answer (score 1):

This paper is proposing a novel and particular production mechanism for thermal relic particles. From what I can gather though it does not motivate special detection mechanisms. So that answers your question with a "no".